# Solrmeter Compilation Error : method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: solr, solrmeter

Am not a JAVA guy, To test my Solr setup was trying to install Solrmeter from
[**Source**](https://github.com/tflobbe/solrmeter/blob/wiki/Usage.md#compile-from-trunk)

and got a compilation error.

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Errors seems to be at two locations

1. ConstantOperationExecutorThread.java:[85,2]

solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\operation\ConstantOperationExecutorThread.java:[85,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

2. CacheHistoryStatistic.java:[246,2]
   \Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\statistic\CacheHistoryStatistic.java:[246,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Below is the error stack trace.

If someone has come across similar issue, please suggest how can I solve this.

```
C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter>mvn package -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.plugtree:solrmeter:jar:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.plugtree:stressTestScope:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.plugtree:solrmeter-parent:pom:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 227, column 36
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Solrmeter parent POM                                               [pom]
[INFO] StressTestScope                                                    [jar]
[INFO] SolrMeter                                                          [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.plugtree:solrmeter-parent >--------------------
[INFO] Building Solrmeter parent POM 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT                       [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.plugtree:stressTestScope >--------------------
[INFO] Building StressTestScope 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT                            [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter\stressTestScope\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter\stressTestScope\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter\stressTestScope\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.plugtree.stressTestScope.TestModule
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running com.plugtree.stressTestScope.TestObject
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.plugtree.stressTestScope.TestScopeTestCase
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/Sarge/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/2.0/guice-2.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
com.plugtree.stressTestScope.TestObject@58a90037
com.plugtree.stressTestScope.TestObject2@74294adb
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.401 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) @ stressTestScope ---
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter\stressTestScope\target\stressTestScope-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.plugtree:solrmeter >-----------------------
[INFO] Building SolrMeter 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT                                  [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ solrmeter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 24 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ solrmeter ---
[INFO] Compiling 111 source files to C:\Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\operation\ConstantOperationExecutorThread.java:[85,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] \Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\statistic\CacheHistoryStatistic.java:[246,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Solrmeter parent POM 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  0.028 s]
[INFO] StressTestScope 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  4.547 s]
[INFO] SolrMeter 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... FAILURE [  4.631 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.572 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-28T08:35:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project solrmeter: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\operation\ConstantOperationExecutorThread.java:[85,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] \Users\Sarge\solrmeter\solrmeter\src\main\java\com\plugtree\solrmeter\model\statistic\CacheHistoryStatistic.java:[246,2] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project solrmeter: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :solrmeter
```

Comment: ConstantOperationExecutorThread and CacheHistoryStatistic.java are implementing any class or extending any class and not oevrriding the abstract methof from that class.

Comment: or try removing @override from the methods which are giving errors

Comment: I checked out the code md run mvn install...I got build success...Reactor Summary:
[INFO] Solrmeter parent POM ............................... SUCCESS [  1.191 s]
[INFO] StressTestScope .................................... SUCCESS [ 49.540 s]
[INFO] SolrMeter .......................................... SUCCESS [01:26 min]
[INFO] --
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --
[INFO] Total time: 02:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-28T18:47:07+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/303M

Comment: I think you are using command mvn package....use mvn clean install....it should work for you

Comment: Thanks, let me try that. Actually it was mentioned in documentation to use mvn package. https://github.com/tflobbe/solrmeter/blob/wiki/Usage.md#compile-from-trunk

Comment: Unfortunately, not working for me
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Solrmeter parent POM 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  0.661 s]
[INFO] StressTestScope 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  6.347 s]
[INFO] SolrMeter 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... FAILURE [  5.112 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.581 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-29T13:23:47+05:30
[INFO] --------------------

Comment: will try removing @override

Comment: Results :

Failed tests:   testLoadStringsFromFileInternationalCharactersUtf8(com.plugtree.solrmeter.FileUtilsTest): Failed for character C3A2 expected:<......> but was:<...83C2...>

Tests run: 110, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Solrmeter parent POM 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  0.644 s]
[INFO] StressTestScope 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  6.414 s]
[INFO] SolrMeter 0.3.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... FAILURE [01:36 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:44 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-29T13:30:37+05:30
[INFO] ------------------

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project solrmeter: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Ashutosh\solrmeter\solrmeter\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

Comment: on removing @override, was receiving above failure report.

Comment: I just checked out the code and run mvn clean install...I am able create the jar in target folder...